# Express 4 router implying parameter regex?

Tags: regex, node.js, express

I have got a simple issue where I have 2 routes which do different things, one is:

`blah\groups\:group_id`

and then

`blah\groups\count`

Now the first returns a specific group, the latter returns the amount of groups the user has access to. Now the problem is that the first route is hit even when I use the 2nd route url. Which makes sense as it doesnt know that there is a different route for `count`. I was looking at doing regex to tell it to use group_id if it does not contain `count` however then I cannot use the `router.param` with it, so is there a way to tell express to use count first then if that isnt matched try the `group_id` one? or if not any way to keep the parameter name but attach some regex so it has the context of what to look for but retains the parameter name?

Comment: Placing the second route before the first one should match it first before the parameters. Can you post some relevant code?

Comment: You are 100% correct, for some reason the change had not gone through, but when I shut down webstorm and loaded it again it seemed to work as expected with the count being fired first. Can you put it as an answer and I will give you the points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Routes work like middleware and are executed in the order they are placed.

Having `blah\groups\count` before `blah\groups\:group_id` will make sure a match of `count` comes before `:group_id`.